# Primefaces 6.0 xhtml page showing blank on redirect from another page

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

Using Primefaces 6.0/jsf 2.2.6.

I have a page (secure), which includes another page (unsecure, there are 2 points of entry to the unsecure page hence this setup) backed by a bean, which uses a template, which is determined at runtime i.e.:

so first secure page has:

```
<h:body>
        <ui:include src="../unsecure/eacCalculator.xhtml" />
</h:body>
```

Second page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("keypress", ":input:not(text,textarea)", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    </script>
</h:head>
<ui:composition template="#{eacCalculatorBean.template}" >
    <f:event listener="#{eacCalculatorBean.getScreenStartupData()}" type="preRenderComponent" />
    <ui:define name="page-content">



.......
```

If I click on page's URL directly after login from a dynamically built menu item, then page loads fine. If I however go to another page first and then from there click again on the menu item of above page it loads a blank page. If I re-click on menu item, page re-renders fine again.

What possible reasons could it be for not loading first time after another page loaded?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please create an [mcve].

Comment: It's too complex as the menu items are built dynamically

Comment: Sorry, but if you cannot create an [mcve] (is the dynamic menu needed to reproduce the problem? Can't it be just left out?) I doubt anyone is able to help you. The javascript is e.g. certaintly not relevant I think

Answer (score 0):

You use an relative path to the include file. If your second page is located inside a different path as the after-login-page, maybe the file location can't be resolved.

- take a look as the AS logfile if file location can't be resolved
- Try absolute path inside template to exclude this problem

  `<ui:include src="/path/to/unsecure/eacCalculator.xhtml" />`

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much debugging I actually found the issue. The fact that "which template to use" is delayed till bean is created caused the CustomMenu inside the xhtml to only fire after  the Bean was instantiated. To make a long story short, it was then using the previous screens settings which was causing the css to slide the data to the right (which made it blank on the screen).